# Is it possible to access php variables/constant via multiple colons?

Tags: php, syntax

I know it is possible to nest arrays or objects and access them like this:

```
some_array["sub_type1"]["value"]
```

or

```
some_object->sub_type1->value
```

But is it also possible to use some kind of nested constant values and acces them like this?

```
SOME_CLASS::SUB_TYPE::MORE_SUBTYPES::VALUE
```

Comment: As class constants are always available even from outside the class, why would you ever need to?

Comment: It's possible to do with [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), but with slightly different syntax

Answer (score 2):

Use class inheritance for your subtypes, and define the constant in the corresponding subtype class definition.

```
<?php
class Someclass {}
class Someclass_Subtype extends Someclass {}
class Someclass_Subtype_Child extends Someclass_Subtype
{
    const VALUE = 'whatever';
}
```

Comment: That is such an abuse of classes. It hurts :(

Comment: How so?  I'm not suggesting those should actually be empty classes, but that the OP should use classes for inheritance, and not somehow hijack constants for that purpose ;)

Comment: true, but he could probably benefit from namespacing and then he'd avoid the heresy associated with classes that have no state

Comment: I think that's a really good suggestion.  Much better than saying "It hurts" ;)

Comment: And I might be reading too far into the "Subtype" pattern implied by the question, but that doesn't seem to be handled simply by namespacing.